# Ordered list css and subsections

Tags: html, css, list

I'm trying to create an ordered list which has subsections in decimal and css-ing like in the image below.

[image: What i want it do be]

but so far i've only managed to get this (the next image below) which now has the numbers but they're aligned off.

[image: what it is so far]

heres my code so far:

```
<style>
    body{
        width: 500px;
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 12px;
        counter-reset:section;
    }

    OL { counter-reset: item }
    LI { display: block }
    LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
    p{
        display:inline-block;
        width: 400px;
    }

</style>

<ol>
  <li>
    <strong>The Card</strong>
    <ol>
        <li><p>When you receive your Card, you will receive a PUK and you must choose a PIN.</p></li>
        <li><p>You must either memorise the PIN or keep record of it in a safe place, separate from your Card. Do not tell anyone your PUK or PIN.</p></li>
    </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Just so you know: there is no need to write element selectors in caps in CSS markup.

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying your li style like this:

```css
OL { margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0; }
```

And add this:

```css
li p { padding-left: 10px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your `li:before` CSS rule. You might also need to play with the `<p>` `margin` CSS properties depending on how you want to align elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your `padding` to 0:

```css
li p {padding: 0; display: block;}
```

And if you want to push it in a bit you could even play around with:

```
list-style-position: outside/inside/inherit
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what got it for me:

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  counter-reset: section;
}
OL { 
  counter-reset: item; 
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
LI { 
  display: block;
}
LI:before { 
  content: counters(item, ".") " "; 
  counter-increment: item ;
  vertical-align: top;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
strong {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
ol li ol {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-botom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You should only post the relevant changes, e.g. body is irrelevant. Also it looks like [Skyhawk's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17322128/1047823) was the way to go, so it would be only fair to accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

There you go (exactly as you want): [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BANDP/2/)

---

CSS

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  counter-reset: section;
}
ol li ol {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
ol li ol li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```html
<ol>
   <li> <strong>The Card</strong>
      <ol>
         <li>
            <p>When you receive your Card, you will receive a PUK and you must choose a PIN.</p>
         </li>
         <li>
             <p>You must either memorise the PIN or keep record of it in a safe place, separate from your Card. Do not tell anyone your PUK or PIN.</p>
         </li>
      </ol>
   </li>
</ol>
```